# Why is the following $\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}}$ equal to $\frac{1}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve an exercise with ratio test. I need an explanation why the following equation below is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$ 
$$\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}}$$

Thanks in advance, i am going to need some help with tags :)

Comment: Note that $a^u \cdot a^v =a^{u+v}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

note that $3^{n+1}=3^n\cdot 3$

Comment: thank you dr Graubner

Comment: i wish you a nice evening!

Answer (score 0):

Note that by definition

$$3^n=3\cdot 3 \cdot 3\cdot...\cdot 3 \quad\text{n times}$$